# Улучшить страницу справки: "Привилегии > Отмечать тревогой"

Tags: предложение, справка, привилегии

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

> Не соответствует тематике сайта, **не являтеся вопросом**,

Во-первых, опечатка, во-вторых, тревоги "Не является вопросом" у нас вроде нет.

> слишком специфичный, не конструктивный

Причин закрытия "Too localized", "Not constructive" у нас никогда не было, и на EN SO они уже удалены. Вероятно, нужно заменить на те причины, которые реально есть.

> повтор вопроса.

Повтор -> Дубликат

> Когда следует отмечать сообщение тревогой?
>   Если вы видите на сайте содержимое, из-за которого вам некомфортно или вы считаете, что оно неуместно, пожалуйста, **отметить** сообщение тревогой для того, чтобы привлечь к нему внимание.

Опечатка "отметить" -> "отметьте". Кроме того, сама формулировка странная. Тревогать все, из-за чего "некомфортно", или все-таки только то, что нарушает правила? Перевод англоязычной справки, впрочем, точный.

> Участники с привилегией «инструменты модератора» видят оскорбительные сигналы тревоги для сообщений и могут отреагировать соответствующе.

Этого функционала больше нет, насколько я знаю. Из соответствующей [англоязычной страницы](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) эту фразу убрали.