# Давайте уже добавим новые версии страниц в справку!

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, справка

На мете есть инициатива по сбору всех дефектов из справки: [Собираем все дефекты из справки в одном месте!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12602/532877) 
Есть также [список](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13149/532877) переписанных/переведённых страниц. Продублирую его и здесь, только уже на русском:

- Три страницы переписаны полностью из-за того, что устарели:

  - [Почему публикация ответов, которые были созданы искусственным интеллектом (например, chatGPT), недопустима?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13141/532877)
  - [Что означает статус вопроса [закрыт]? Почему некоторые вопросы закрывают?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12932/532877)
  - [Общие сообщения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13079/532877)
- Пять страниц переведены на русский язык.

  - [Как пользоваться очередью «Первые вопросы»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13136/532877)
  - [Как пользоваться очередью «Первые ответы»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13137/532877)
  - [Кто такие сотрудники и какова их роль здесь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12632/532877)
  - [Политики Соглашения Модератора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12630/532877)
  - [Что такое уведомление о нарушении DMCA и почему моё сообщение было удалено?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12621/532877)
- Одна страница должна быть удалена. С причинами удаления можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13135/532877).

  - [Как пользоваться очередью первых сообщений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts)
- На одной странице не хватает абзаца:

  - [Меньше рекламы — абзац, который "пропал" из статьи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13041/532877)

## Давайте уже добавим это всё в справочный центр!

Новые версии есть, <s>техзадание</s> список на <s>басурмансокм</s> английском для сотрудника есть. Пора звать персонал!

**P.S**: если у вас есть, что высказать по поводу новых версий страниц справки, то вы можете это сделать с помощью комментариев к постам с переводами/переписанными страницами. Раз скоро добавляем в справку, всё должно выглядеть идеально!

Comment: "Пора звать персонал!" хорошо бы, но как это сделать?!

Comment: @чистов_n у модераторов есть специальные чаты. В них ещё недавно заявку на проведение выборов подавали. Недавно - это этой весной.

Comment: Нет смысла плодить темы, это ничего не ускорит. Нам нужен новый процесс внесения изменений в справку, раньше это делал Николас, теперь среди сотрудников некому этим заниматься. Кто-то должен это проверять, утверждать и передавать сотрудникам. О переписывании десятка статей и речи нет, хотя бы поправить опечатки, которые несколько лет висят, уже было бы неплохо...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight "о переписывании 10 статьей и речи нет" - но они уже переписаны! И вставить текст ctrl+c ctrl+v по-моему сотруднику несложно. Насчёт того, что нужен новый механизм - нужно дать модераторам справку редактировать.

Comment: Сложно или не сложно, сейчас это не делается. Я 3 года назад указывал на опечатки (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9976/), тогда еще Николас был, но ничего не исправлено.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight значит будет делатся :) Всё-таки 10 переписанных полностью статьей важнее, чем опечатка какая-нибудь. К тому же, три года назад [Николас уже не был КМ'ом ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7545), и за каждой опечаткой в справке уже не следил, т.к. это не входило в его обязанности. Сейчас я прошу пингануть в закрытом чате персоналу, чтобы он пришёл И СДЕЛАЛ.

Comment: Добавил метку, которая технически должна привлечь внимание персонала.